# Google analytics : Import independent data ( Website tracking )

Tags: google-analytics

Is there a way to include (import) data into Google analytics without having any common column ?

P.S : I have gone through the DATA IMPORT and it helps only in related data .

Answer (score 0):

No. You can send data via the measurement protocol, but only in realtime, one hit a time (technically 20 hits at a time, but I never got [batched requests](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide#batch) to work).

But you cannot create new hits via a data import, which is the same as to say you can only amend existing data, and for that you need a key field that relates new data to existing data (as you have already found out).